# Make an Esri shapefile from a numpy array using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, numpy

I have an Esri shapefile that I have dropped duplicates from and turned into a numpy array using the following code:

```
loc_ID_fld_names = ["LocIDNmbr", "Lat", "Long"]
loc_ID_array = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(Data,loc_ID_fld_names)
uniqueLocIDs_array = list(set(locIDNmbr))
locIDs_df = pd.DataFrame(loc_ID_array)
locIDs_df_no_dupes = locIDs_df.drop_duplicates(subset=["LocIDNmbr"])
locIDs_df_no_dupes = locIDs_df_no_dupes.to_numpy()
```

Now I want to know how to go back and turn it to an Esri shapefile. I want to do this in the ArcPy terminal on ArcGIS Pro and not using the API, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [NumPyArrayToFeatureClass](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/numpyarraytofeatureclass.htm) function.  The array needs to be in a [Structured Array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html) format and you can convert your `ndarray` to this using [`np.rec.fromarrays`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromarrays.html). E.g.

```
import numpy as np
etc...
locIDs_df_no_dupes = locIDs_df_no_dupes.to_numpy()
locIDs_array_no_dupes = np.rec.fromarrays(locIDs_df_no_dupes.T, dtype=loc_ID_array.dtype)
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(locIDs_array_no_dupes, out_shp, ['Long', 'Lat'], arcpy.Describe(Data).spatialReference)
```